# topic related to electrostatic

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Is work done by external agent in moving charges in electric field from a point to infinity  equal to work done by external agent in the same charge from infinity to the same point ?

Comment: What you've told is true as long as you do it infinitely slowly. You should move the charge such that it does not gain any kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1):

The work done in the two cases will be equal in magnitude but different in sign.

When a test charge (unit positive charge) is moved opposite to the direction of electric field, work done by external agent is positive and when the test charge is moved along the direction of electric field then the work done by external agent is negative.